# Would like someone to double check code for 8bit up counter with enable

Tags: vhdl

I am a novice coder and don't know if what I did was correct so I would appreciate if someone could double check it for me.

So im trying to make an 8-bit up counter with an active-low count enable control signal. The counter should advance to the next count if cten = 0 and stops at the current count if cten = 1. The counter resets into a state that outputs binary 0 and progresses upward on each clock edge when counting is enabled until it reaches 255. It locks in the state producing output 255. I also tried to change the clock to 1Hz clock from a 50MHz clock the is on a FPGA board that will be used to run some instructions (with there being no more than 255 instructions, hence wanting to lock at that number) based off the count value of int_q.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is
port(
    clk, rst, cten: in std_logic;
    q: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity counter;

architecture moore of counter is
 signal d,int_q: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 signal cnt:     integer range 0 to 25000;
 signal clk1Hz:  std_logic;
 
begin

    -- drive internal Q signal to output signal
    q <= int_q;
    -- next-state logic: add 1 unless 255, lock at 255
    d <= int_q+1 when int_q < 255;
    d <= int_q   when int_q = 255;
    
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            cnt <= cnt+1;
            if cnt = 25000 then
                clk1Hz <= not clk1Hz;
                cnt <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- register process
    process(all)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk1Hz) then
        if rst ='1' then int_q <= "00000000";
            elsif cten = '0' then int_q <= int_q+1;
                else int_q <= int_q;
        end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
end architecture moore;
```

Comment: What did the compiler and simulation say?

Comment: i didn't get any errors and i did not run a simulation, i was more so seeing if someone could confirm my biggest worry of whether the clock stuff is correct for making a 50MHz clock to a 1Hz

Comment: Yet there's a syntax error - no library clause making the library name ieee visible. There are additional errors. This effort doesn't satisfy the fill in the blanks requirement of your [Need help to complete a provided code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867155/need-help-to-complete-a-provided-code-snippet) and should be merged with that question. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: should be ok now, i didnt bring the library ieee; line down on so it ended up not showing up

Comment: Trying to resist the urge to down vote this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as it lacks a specific programming problem and lacking context of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867155/need-help-to-complete-a-provided-code-snippet) is not a practical, answerable problem. Perhaps you should return to the original question, your effort shown here has structural issues, such as d not being evaluated in one of those original **<<Complete>>** fill ins. There are additional issues.

Comment: Do you want us to review the code? That's not what Stack Overflow is for. Instead, ask this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). On Stack overflow we help with problems. So either focus on a problem, or move it IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. If `rst` is unasserted on the rising edge of `clk1Hz`, then `int_q` will remain in an unknown state.
2. `clk1Hz` is never initialized, so the `not` operation does nothing.
3. `cnt` is never initialized, so incrementing it does nothing.
4. `int_q` is being driven in 2 places: both inside and outside a process.
5. signal `d` is unused, did you want to connect it to `q`?
6. You're only counting to 25_000, but if your source clock is 50 MHz, you need to count to 25_000_000.
7. If you want a synchronous reset, (which given the name "Moore", I bet this is homework), it's good practice to create a new process specifically to internally synchronize that async reset signal to the system clock, maybe through a 2FF synchronizer for one idea.

If I understood the question correctly, this should get you in the ballpark:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is
port(
    clk, rst, cten: in std_logic;
    q: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity counter;

architecture moore of counter is
 signal int_q: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 signal cnt:     integer range 0 to 25_000_000;
 signal clk1Hz:  std_logic;

begin

    -- indicate when at 255
    q <= '1' when int_q = 255 else '0';

    process(rst, clk)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            --  need to assign initial values
            clk1Hz <= '0';
            cnt <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if cnt = 25_000_000 then
                clk1Hz <= not clk1Hz;
                cnt <= 0;
            else
                cnt <= cnt+1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- register process
    process(rst, clk1Hz)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            int_q <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk1Hz) then
            if cten = '0' then
                int_q <= int_q+1;   --  rolls over
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture moore;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map this in an FPGA you cannot generate a clock like you do. Clocks are very special signals with strict electrical requirements. If you need a 1Hz frequency clock and the frequency of your master clock is 50MHz there are basically two options:

- Use a clock manager/generator hard macro of your FPGA if it has some, and configure it to generate a 1Hz clock from your master clock. Explicitly pass the output through a clock buffer if your tools don't do it automatically.
- Do not generate a 1Hz clock, use an enable signal that you assert high once every 50M clock periods. Or use a rescaler and increment your counter only when the rescaler reaches a predefined value.

As the first option depends on your FPGA, your tools, etc. let's investigate the second:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is
  generic(freqHz: positive := 50000000);
  port(clk, rst, cten: in std_ulogic;
       q: out std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0));
end entity counter;

architecture moore of counter is
  signal rescaler: integer range 0 to freqHz - 1;
  signal cnt:      integer range 0 to 255;
begin
  q <= std_ulogic_vector(to_unsigned(cnt, 8));

  process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      if rst = '1' then
        rescaler <= freqHz - 1;
        cnt      <= 0;
      elsif cnt /= 255 then
        if rescaler /= 0 then
          rescaler <= rescaler - 1;
        else
          rescaler <= freqHz - 1;
          cnt      <= cnt + 1;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture moore;
```

Remarks:

- Use `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` or `ieee.numeric_std` but not both. And as noted by @JHBonarius, do not use `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` at all. It is not standard and deprecated. Use `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned`, instead.
- I added a generic parameter (`freqHz`) with a default value such that you can easily adapt to different clock frequencies.
- The 50Mhz to 1Hz rescaler is decremented instead of incremented because a hardware zero detector is frequently slightly smaller and faster than an arbitrary value detector.
- If you do not know the difference between `std_logic` and `std_ulogic`, always use `std_ulogic`, never `std_logic` (and use `std_ulogic_vector` instead of `std_logic_vector`, `u_unsigned` instead of `unsigned`...) One day or another you will really need `std_logic` and this day you will understand the difference, and why you should (almost) never use it. And do not listen to people who tell you that `std_logic` is more standard or better supported by the tools or whatever. They are wrong. The only exception is your teacher or your boss: even if they are wrong, it might be better to obey.

Comment: _"Use ieee.std_logic_unsigned or"_ ?? I thought we went for `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned`. about 14 years ago and deprecated the `std_logic_[un]signed/_artih` stuff?

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, you're right. But this is what the OP does. I will add a recommendation of not using `std_logic_unsigned`.